# Given this array, how can I reformat it to look like this

Tags: php, arrays, format

If I had an array:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'manufacturers_id' => 29,
        'manufacturers_name' => 'Quicksilver',
        'products_quantity' => 1,
        'products_price' => 15.6000,
        'products_cost' => 8.0000,
    ),
    array(
        'manufacturers_id' => 29,
        'manufacturers_name' => 'Quicksilver',
        'products_quantity' => 2,
        'products_price' => 4.6722,
        'products_cost' => 2.4000,
    )
);
```

How can I reformat this to provide the structure

```
Array
 (
 [Quiksilver] => Array
    (
        [brands_sales] => $brandsSalesVal
        [brands_products_sold] => $brandsSoldVal
        [brands_costs] => $brandsCostsVal
    )
```

`$brandsSalesVal` = A sum of all the products_price * products_quantity (for each manufacturer_id)

`$brandsSoldVal`= A sum of all the products_quantity for each manufacturer

`$brandsCostsVal`= A sum of all the products_costs for each manufacturer

Any help is greatly appreciated and I am thankful for anyone to take time to answer my rather lengthy query. I am still getting to grips with reformating arrays.

Comment: Yuo iterate through the given array and create a new one out of the alements of the iterated one. What is the problem here?

Comment: Well, thats what I need to do. I just dont know how, is all.

Comment: Sorry, but you should at least _try_ to do it. You won't learn anything otherwise. And this is not a place to dump your code, lean back and have others do your work. That is not fair.

Comment: Thanks for the continued support.

Comment: Come on, don't be a dick. I don't make this comment to annoy you or to be a pain in the ass. But there are rules for questions asked here. Maybe you should read them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `foreach` loop like so:

```
// Declare the totals array and
// the manufacturers->id map
$totals = array();
$manufacturers = array();

// Loop through the array of products and populate
// the totals array
foreach($data as $value){

    // Set the key to the manufacturers name
    $key = $value['manufacturers_name'];

    // If the array has not been built yet, then ensure the
    // values are set to 0 and add the manufacturer to the 
    // manufacturers map if it is not already there
    if(!isset($totals[$key])){
        // Add the manufacturer to the map
        $manufacturers[$value['manufacturers_id']] = $key;
        // Default the values to 0
        $totals[$key]['brand_sales'] = 0;
        $totals[$key]['brands_products_sold'] = 0;
        $totals[$key]['brands_costs'] = 0;
    }

    // Calculate the brand sales
    $totals[$key]['brand_sales'] += ($value['products_price']*$value['products_quantity']);

    // Calculate the brand sales
    $totals[$key]['brands_products_sold'] += $value['products_quantity'];

    // Calculate the brand sales
    $totals[$key]['brands_costs'] += $value['products_cost'];
}
```

In order to access the information stored in the array generated above, you can use another `foreach` loop like so:

```
// Loop through the $totals array and print the result
foreach($totals as $key => $value){

    // Print the manufacturers name and ID
    echo "\n".$key." (ID: ".array_search($key,$manufacturers).")";

    // Print the totals for the current manufacturer
    echo "\n\tBrand Sales: ".$values['brand_sales'];
    echo "\n\tBrand Products Sold: ".$values['brands_products_sold'];
    echo "\n\tBrand Costs: ".$values['brands_costs'];
}
```

*The `array_search` function is used to look up the ID of the manufacturer based on the manufacturers name stored in the `$manufacturers` array. You can alter the code so that it does not need the `array_search` function, but I have done it like this because traditionally you would map the ID->NAME, not NAME->ID. It is just personal preference...*

For more information on the `foreach` loop, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: @billyonecan Why will you get undefined index notices?

Comment: Yeah. See this:
$totals[$value['manufacturers_name']]['brand_sales'] += ($value['products_price']*$value['products_quantity']);
The values don't exist yet, so they will default as '0', but they'll also throw notices

Comment: @billyonecan Just amended, my mistake :-). Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: A suggestion also: You should cast '$value['manufacturers_name']' into a variable so that PHP doesn't have to re-evaluate the array to determine the value every time it's used. Adding: $manufacturer_name = $value['manufacturers_name'] at the start of the loop (and replacing all those references with the variable instead) will make the code way more readable and also perform better

Comment: This really is marvelous. I'm now trying to figure out how it knows which products_price belong to which manufacturers_id

Comment: @Aleski You can create an array that maps the manufacturers name to the manufacturers ID, and then you can just reference... Would you like me to post an example?

Comment: I mean in your example you already have. It works perfectly but I'm not sure how each product, belonging to a specific manufacturer, knows it is (is it the key perhaps?). For the record it works but I just dont know how to see it.

Comment: @Aleski Yes, the key is the manufacturers name. I have added a couple of lines that create a map of id->manufacturer_name. I will now post an example of how you can access the data... Give me 2 mins :-)

Comment: What is the manufacturers map of ids useful for? Also, could you give an example of how I would output it in a `foreach();` (unless thats being too cheeky)

Comment: @Aleski Please see the update. The `$manufacturers` array is simply an array to map the ID of the brand to the name of the brand... Otherwise, retrieving the brand from the original array would not be too practical. See my update and it should become clearer :-)

Comment: Thanks Ben, this has been a great help. Contrary to what people might think, I learn best when I can look at examples of solutions and understand the patterns/methods taken. Thanks greatly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'manufacturers_id' => 29,
        'manufacturers_name' => 'Quicksilver',
        'products_quantity' => 1,
        'products_price' => 15.6000,
        'products_cost' => 8.0000,
    ),
    array(
        'manufacturers_id' => 29,
        'manufacturers_name' => 'Quicksilver',
        'products_quantity' => 2,
        'products_price' => 4.6722,
        'products_cost' => 2.4000,
    )
    ,
    array(
        'manufacturers_id' => 30,
        'manufacturers_name' => 'Different Brand',
        'products_quantity' => 2,
        'products_price' => 4.6722,
        'products_cost' => 2.4000,
    )
);

$sortedData = array();
foreach($data as $num => $row){
    $manufacturersName = $row['manufacturers_name'];
    //If we don't have an array made for the manufacturer yet, make one
    if(!isset($sortedData[$manufacturersName])){
        $sortedData[$manufacturersName] = array(
            'brands_sales' => 0,
            'brands_products_sold' => 0,
            'brands_costs' => 0
        );
    };
    //Make a reference to the relevant manufacturer sorted data
    $manufacturerData = &$sortedData[$manufacturersName];
    $qty = $row['products_quantity'];
    //
    $manufacturerData['brands_sales']           += $qty * $row['products_price'];
    $manufacturerData['brands_products_sold']   += $qty;
    $manufacturerData['brands_costs']           += $row['products_cost'];
}

var_dump($sortedData); // <- your result.
```

Result:

```
array (size=2)
  'Quicksilver' => 
    array (size=3)
      'brands_sales' => float 24.9444
      'brands_products_sold' => int 3
      'brands_costs' => float 10.4
  'Different Brand' => 
    array (size=3)
      'brands_sales' => float 9.3444
      'brands_products_sold' => int 2
      'brands_costs' => float 2.4
```

Comment: Im getting `Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array` on the part with the `(int)`

Comment: Not sure why that's happening. Give me a moment I'll test it out.

Comment: Okay, fully tested now. I hit that scalar value issue as well and now it's resolved. Give it another shot?

Comment: Also I should add; if you have 2 brands of the exact same name (but different ID's) you will end up merging their data and causing chaos. You should probably use the ID as the grouping parameter to remove any risk.